# Weird list in Python

Tags: python, list, discord, discord.py

I was trying to fetch a member of my discord server using *discord.py*. Using the guild.members I was iterating over it, and it returned me the names of the members, but then I printed it directly and I got something like this:

```py
[<Member id=102833403109497170 name='Xiaoling' discriminator='147' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=102393565654216714 name='DarkFuture' chunked=True member_count=22>>, <Member id=94117068084664839 name='Rishit' discriminator='0184' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=1023935685654216714 name='DarkFuture' chunked=True member_count=22>>, <Member id=9417194317169792 name='麦わら帽子・Zoro' discriminator='905' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=102393565654216714 name='DarkFuture' chunked=True member_count=22>>]
```

Is this a List? I checked its type, and it said list, but it didn't look like a list to me. If I paste it directly in the code editor, there's an error highlighting, and if I run it, it gives me a syntax error. What is this? How is Python iterating over it?

I just found a weird list in Python which I don't know what is and I needed the information.

Comment: it is containing Member object? I am very confused why are there < and > s and if it is a valid list why is it throwing a syntax error?

Comment: I sort of understood that it contains a member object, but how is it iterating over it and returning the name from that object?

Comment: Classes can define a custom display format for printing themselves.  It is not meant to be interpreted directly as code.

Comment: I see, But still the same question, How is it iterating over it to get only `name` out of it and how do I access other attributes like `id` and `descriminator`

Comment: It's an object.  Assuming you don't want to read the documentation, as you should, you might try `lst[0].name` .

Comment: I'll try, Can I get the link to the docs that explains this part of the list? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the class Member

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self,id,name,somethingElse=True):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.somethingElse = somethingElse

    def addExtraValue(self,extra):
        self.extra = extra
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<id = {}, name = '{}'>".format(self.id, self.name)
```

Here,
the Member class has its own attributes like `id`, `name`, etc.

Let's create a list of this class

```
m1 = Member(1,'name 1')
m1.addExtraValue(15)
m2 = Member(2,'name 2', False)

members = [m1,m2]
```

When we print `members` at this point. It will show output like,

```
[<id = 1, name = 'name 1'>, <id = 2, name = 'name 2'>]
```

instead of

```
[<__main__.Member object at 0x7fb9c093e4c0>, <__main__.Member object at 0x7fb9c07e8130>]
```

It is due to the `def __repr__(self)` function in class, which is used to create custom output.

I hope this will clear the confusion regarding the print of `<` mark in the output.

Then, Class attributes are not iterable, hence we can not directly iterate over it or can not access the attributes as a list (i.e. `member[key]` is not supported).

To solve this issue you can use the `eval` method as shown below.

```
possibleKeys = ['id','name','somethingElse','extra']
for member in members:
    for key in possibleKeys:
        try:
            value = eval('member.{}'.format(key))
        except:
            value = 'Not Available'
        print("{} => {}".format(key,value))
    print()
```

The `eval` is wrapped in `try and catch` because the `extra` attribute is not necessary to be available in all class objects.

I hope this will clear the way to iterate over class objects to get other attributes.